# Klocwork logs file size and rotation

Tags: logging, klocwork

Did anyone find where and how to configure the log level and rotation of the klocwork.log?
The default is "INFO" and no rotation, so after a while, the file becomes HUGE!
The support [site](https://support.roguewave.com/documentation) documentation is very shallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found an answer:

Instruction:
1. stop the klocwork server
2. remove the current klocwork.log from /log to a backup directory for storage
3. start the klocwork server
4 Open the logging configuration web page by adding #logconf to the end of the Klocwork portal URL in the browser after login. For example:
http://klocwork_server1:8080/review/insight-review.html#logconf

When "Logging Configuration" is open, replace everything in it with the text below:

```
log4j.defaultInitOverride = false
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,MAIN_LOG
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=<KW server installed directory>/projects_root/logs/klocwork.log 
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.append=true
```

NOTE: Replace  with your installed directory.

Click the Apply button at the right bottom. The log rotation will take effect immediately.